# How to handle device plug/unplug with Web MIDI?

Tags: javascript, web, midi, web-midi

I am working on an online musical score reading trainer, [a prototype is available here](http://clef1.com). I was able to implement access to previously connected MIDI keyboard, however, I am struggling to implement a hot plug/unplug scenario.

My last take looks like this:

```
    setupDevices(inputs){
    let deviceName = '';

    inputs.forEach((value, key, map) => {
        if (value.connection === 'open' || value.connection === 'pending' ){

            value.open().then((midiInput) => {
                console.log(`Opened ${midiInput.name}`);
                midiInput.onmidimessage = midiController.onMIDIMessage;
            }, null);
        } else {
            value.onmidimessage = null;
        }
    });

    if (deviceName.length === 0) {
        deviceName = 'none';
    }

    document.getElementById('connectedDevice').setAttribute('value', deviceName);
},

onMIDISuccess(midiAccess) {
    midiAccess.onstatechange = (evt) => {
        console.log('MIDI config changed');
        midiController.setupDevices(evt.currentTarget.inputs);
    };
}
```

When debugging all the promises get called with good looking arguments, but I am not able to receive any key down messages. Also console.log(`Opened ${midiInput.name}`) gets called many more times than expected:

```
midiController.js:57 MIDI config changed
midiController.js:40 Opened KOMPLETE KONTROL - 1
midiController.js:57 MIDI config changed
midiController.js:40 Opened KOMPLETE KONTROL - 1
midiController.js:57 MIDI config changed
midiController.js:40 Opened KOMPLETE KONTROL - 1
midiController.js:40 Opened KOMPLETE KONTROL EXT - 1
midiController.js:40 Opened KOMPLETE KONTROL - 1
3
midiController.js:40 Opened KOMPLETE KONTROL EXT - 1
midiController.js:57 MIDI config changed
midiController.js:40 Opened KOMPLETE KONTROL - 1
midiController.js:40 Opened KOMPLETE KONTROL EXT - 1
midiController.js:57 MIDI config changed
midiController.js:40 Opened KOMPLETE KONTROL - 1
midiController.js:40 Opened KOMPLETE KONTROL EXT - 1
2
midiController.js:40 Opened Komplete Kontrol DAW - 1
midiController.js:57 MIDI config changed
midiController.js:40 Opened KOMPLETE KONTROL - 1
midiController.js:40 Opened KOMPLETE KONTROL EXT - 1
midiController.js:57 MIDI config changed
midiController.js:40 Opened KOMPLETE KONTROL - 1
midiController.js:40 Opened KOMPLETE KONTROL EXT - 1
```

﻿
(all this gets printed just after I just turned the controller on). Any hints?

Comment: The code I posted is already listening to MIDIAccess.onstatechange, but I am unable to re-register for key events.

Comment: I tried with a virtual MIDI device and I also have duplicate reports on my chrome 68 (each port is reported twice). One thing though, when you call *MIDIPort.open*, the MIDIAccess statechange will fire again if the MIDIPort was not yet connected. Same when you simply set its onmidimessage.

Answer (score 0):

```
function midiOnMIDImessage(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
function requestMIDIAccessSuccess(midi) {
        var inputs = midi.inputs.values();
        for (var input = inputs.next(); input && !input.done; input = inputs.next()) {
            input.value.onmidimessage = midiOnMIDImessage;
        }
    }
navigator.requestMIDIAccess().then(requestMIDIAccessSuccess, requestMIDIAccessFailure);
```

See [Working example](https://surikov.github.io/webaudiofont/examples/midikey.html)

Comment: The example is not working well with my controller, which has multiple interfaces (sometimes it connects to the DAW interface instead of the keyboard). But it looks like a promising hint, thanks!

Comment: Btw. your sampler library looks very good, I am going to give it a try.